# Ambiguous amazon tag

Tags: discussion

I've been going through the list of tags that do not yet have wiki. One of tags that falls under this category is the [amazon](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag.

I thought I would create a wiki but gave up on the idea after I had a look at some of the questions tagged with amazon. Most of them are questions about using Alexa or making DIY Echo's. Neither of which in my opinion should be tagged amazon. (In a couple of cases there are questions about people struggling to get a product to work, and tagged it amazon because I assume that's where they got the product from).

My suggestion is creating some new tags to replace the amazon tag, or get rid of it all together and just leave the questions tagged as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good call! A generic [amazon](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag is really of no use in its current form. I would agree to more specific tags (though they would serve a very small number of questions right now) such as [amazon-echo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-echo) (IoT has that) or [alexa](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alexa). Where [amazon](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) is used to merely point out that a gadget has been bought there we should simply get rid of it.